# Why doesn't static works as expected in this lazy loading code?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

The code is simple. It lazy loads a dictionary. If the dictionary is nothing then it fills the dictionary.

However, when I go through the program the code inside `If _countryDictionary Is Nothing Then` is called several times. I wonder what went wrong?

```
   Get
        Static _countryDictionary As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)



        If _countryDictionary Is Nothing Then
            _countryDictionary = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

            Dim listOfCountries = fileToCol(COUNTRYCODESFileName)

            For Each var In listOfCountries
                Dim ar = var.Split({"*"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
                _countryDictionary.Add(LCase(ar(0)), UCase(ar(1)))
            Next
            _countryDictionary.Add("delete", "de")
            _countryDictionary.Add("default", "df")
            _countryDictionary.Add("pakinmay", "py")

        End If

        Return _countryDictionary(country)
    End Get
```

[image]
Here is a screenshot of my debugging. As you see it's still nothing. Does static keywords work differently on get method in vb.net?

Update: Based on the answer, it seems that the static variable here is different for different instance of the class. I always thought the word static means the variable is not in the heap but in the stack or in the code portion. I guess I am wrong.

Comment: Are you creating multiple instances of the containing class?  From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) "When you declare a static variable in a procedure that isn't Shared, only one copy of the variable is available *for each instance* of the class."

Comment: It is shared between different calls to getter but new instance of dictionary will be created for new instance of class

Comment: Ah so static in class get property is different  than static in normal module. I got to move that country dictionary into some module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark pointed in his comment and documents, `Static` keyword define a variable shared between different calls to the procedure where static variable is defined (Getter in your case)

```
Public Class Test

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Integer
        Get
            Static SomeConstant As Integer = 0
            SomeConstant += 1
            Return SomeConstant
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Sub Main()

  Dim test1 As New Test()
  Console.WriteLine(test1 .Value) 'Print 1
  Console.WriteLine(test1 .Value) 'Print 2

  Dim another As New Test()
  Console.WriteLine(another.Value) 'Print 1
  Console.WriteLine(another.Value) 'Print 2

End Sub
```

So in your case getter `countryCode` is executed from different instances of your class.

If you want to share instance between all instances of your class, then create static member by using keyword `Shared`

```
Public Class YourClass

    Private Shared ReadOnly CountryDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public ReadOnly Property CountryCode As String
        Get
            Return YourClass.CountryDictionary("country")
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then use it in same way as you have used `_countryDictionary` variable

Comment: Just a note to people implementing this that that shared field should be _outside_ the setter, on the class its self.

Comment: This is the correct answer. But that's a bit inellegant because other members of the class may change the CountryDictionary variable. I added my own answer to avoid this.

Comment: Of course, the question is why it behaves this way and not how to make this code better. So this is still the right answer. Not my answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative would be the use of the `shared` keyword which is similar to `static` in c#. This creates a "global" variable that can be accessed by all instances of that class. This is probably what you were looking for I think.

```
Shared _countryDictionary As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

Get
    If _countryDictionary Is Nothing Then
        _countryDictionary = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
        ... populate dictionary
```

See [Shared (visual basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx).

Comment: I see. So the _countryDictionary should be "shared" instead of static. And it should be outside the getter. Thanks. I always thought the word static means the variable is not in the heap but in the stack or in the code portion.

Comment: @JimThio - correct, shared is what you are looking for if you want a single instance of a variable accessible from any instance. You also want to declare in your class but outside of your methods / properties although you can access it from in there. If you think you are going to run into a race condition issue like with multi threading or in a web app. you should syncronize the code that populates the dictionary using a lock on either `me` or another `shared` instance of something.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this

```
Private Shared Function countryDictionary() As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Static _countryDictionary As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
    If _countryDictionary Is Nothing Then
        _countryDictionary = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim listOfCountries = fileToCol(COUNTRYCODESFileName)

        For Each var In listOfCountries
            Dim ar = var.Split({"*"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
            _countryDictionary.Add(LCase(ar(0)), UCase(ar(1)))
        Next
        _countryDictionary.Add("delete", "de")
        _countryDictionary.Add("default", "df")
        _countryDictionary.Add("pakinmay", "py")

    End If
    Return _countryDictionary

End Function

Public ReadOnly Property countryCode As String
    Get
        Dim _countryDictionary = countryDictionary()

        Return _countryDictionary(country)
    End Get
End Property
```

This is an addition to other answers. Basically I moved the computationally heavy part of the code to a shared function that lazy loads. Then those that requires the use of some member variables can just call the lazy load function.